# How to reset index of multiple pandas dataframes using a loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas

How to reset index of multiple pandas dataframes using a loop in python?

I have 17 dataframes in a list and I want to reset index for all of them using a loop.

Any help?

Comment: in what structure  you have multiple df eg.in list etc

Comment: Please show us some code so we can help you achieve what you seek

Comment: Yes, my dfs are in a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remember that reset_index is not an inplace operation and you need to reassign or use the `inplace` parameter.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(1,10))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2019-01-1', periods=10))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(index=[*'ABCDEFGHIJ'])

lofdfs = [df1, df2, df3]
for df in lofdfs:
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Or, use list comprehension:

```
[df.reset_index(inplace=True) for df in lofdfs]
```

Answer (score 3):

This would be the simplest way imo:

```
#This list contains the names of all of your dataframes
list_dataframes = [foo1, foo2, foo3, ..... , foo17]

for dataframe in list_dataframes:
    dataframe.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: This will not change the dataframes in list_dataframes because `reset_index` is not an inplace operation.

Comment: Can't understand why if I use `df = df.reset_index()` instead of `dataframe.reset_index(inplace=True)`, it won't work...

Answer (score 1):

Pandas's [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) say:

**reset_index:** Reset the index of the DataFrame, and use the default one instead. If the DataFrame has a MultiIndex, this method can remove one or more levels.

This is util when you has complex dataframe, but if you has separate dataframes you can do like:

```
for df in dataframes:
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: This will not change the df in dataframes, because `reset_index` is not an inplace operation.